# dotnet core logging showing info result always

Tags: asp.net-core, logging

I am learning .net core logging. I have read some blogs and docs also.
I am wondering why it's showing always "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" Information logs every time with following settings.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Error",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error",
      "DemoWeb.Controllers.HomeController":  "Error"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

To double check(If my appsettings.json is working) I added this in ConfigureService.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(config =>
    {
        // clear out default configuration
        config.ClearProviders();

        config.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        config.AddDebug();
        config.AddEventSourceLogger();
        config.AddConsole();                
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

It's working as expected for my own added "HomeController" Class.

I just want to remove "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" from console logs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The file you've shown looks like `appsettings.json`. Do you also have `appsettings.Development.json`? Have a look in there and see what the settings are. My guess is they're overriding the settings you've shown.

Comment: Ohh...Yes you are correct. Many many thanks. @KirkLarkin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as @KirkLarkin mentioned, in development, `appsettings.Development.json` configuration would overwrite values found in `appsettings.json`.

For more information, you can check : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#appsettingsjson

> want to remove "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" from console logs

In your project, multiple [logging providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging-providers) can be enabled. If you just want to turn off `Information` level logs about `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"` from **ConsoleLogger**, you can try to apply log filter rule(s) as below.

```
services.AddLogging(config =>
{
    // clear out default configuration
    config.ClearProviders();

    config.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

    //add log filter for ConsoleLoggerProvider
    config.AddFilter<ConsoleLoggerProvider>("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogLevel.Error);

    config.AddDebug();
    config.AddEventSourceLogger();
    config.AddConsole();
});
```

And you can achieve same by [configuring logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-logging) for that specific provider.

```
"Console": {
  "IncludeScopes": true,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error"
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem was resolved from @KirkLarkin comment, Thanks for sharing the another approach.

Comment: `want to remove "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" from console logs` Hi @HPSingh, if you just want to configure log level for **ConsoleLogger**, please check the approaches that I mentioned.

Comment: Please note that the LogLevel (as you did) will apply to all the enabled providers, not just ConsoleLogger provider.